# Problem in enabling mod_rewrite in Ubuntu

Tags: linux, mod-rewrite

I am trying to change from windows to linux server. And for that i am trying to enable mod_write in ubuntu. I have taken all the necessary steps to enable the mod_rewrite as mod_rewrite is displayed under loaded modules. I have set all the permissions for the .htacess file. But for some reason the rewrite does not appear to be working in the linux server. It was working fine while i was using the same code in windows server.

Can anyone please help me in this issue. Your help will be really appreciated.

Thanks.
Rajan.

Comment: You should add you .htaccess to your question

Answer (score 1):

Check if you have the `AllowOverride` directive set to `None`. This is usually done in a file which sets your VirtualHosts

```
NameVirtualHost 192.168.0.1:80
<VirtualHost 192.168.0.1:80>
    ServerName some.local.site

    DocumentRoot /home/user/site
    <Directory /home/user/site>
            AllowOverride None  <-- set this to All

    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: I had changed this as well but still there appears to be some problem. Anyways thanks for your time and help. Can you provide any further solution please.

Comment: Can you add relevant config sections and the .htaccess to the question body? I think nobody can tell anything beyond what's already has been told without extra information.

Answer (score 1):

If setting `AllowOverride` to `ALL` didn't work, you might want to debug mod_rewrite like so:

add after `RewriteEngine On`

```
RewriteLog "/var/log/httpd/mod_rw.log"
RewriteLogLevel 9
```